# Sending `NSManagedObjects` through HTTP

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a simple subclass of `NSManagedObject` in a simple app supposed to collect data from an iPhone and send the data to a server.

This is what this class looks like:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension TestSession {


    @NSManaged var bootTime: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var accelerometerData: Data?
    @NSManaged var gyroscopeData: Data?
    @NSManaged var motionData: Data?
    @NSManaged var magnetometerData: Data?


}
```

Now, suppose I have an instance `TodaysSession` of `TestSession`, that I'd like to send in a POST request.

What I was doing, until now, was covering this data to a string (say, unarchive `accelerometerData` to get an array of `CMAcceleration` objects, then convert the timestamp, x, y, and z components to CSV format).

This is very inefficient (in terms of string size and time).

I've done some research and found some options : Using `Codable`, though that didn't work for me, `NSKeyedArchiver`

But I'm not sure what advantage each offers, or if there are other, better options out there, that I don't know about (and didn't find in my research, not knowing what to look for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `NSManagedObject` subclass adopt `Encodable` but consider that `Data` types must be `base64Encoded` before being sent in a HTTP request

```
extension TestSession : Encodable {

    @NSManaged var bootTime: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var accelerometerData: Data?
    @NSManaged var gyroscopeData: Data?
    @NSManaged var motionData: Data?
    @NSManaged var magnetometerData: Data?


    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case bootTime, accelerometerData, gyroscopeData, motionData, magnetometerData}

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(bootTime, forKey: .bootTime)
        try container.encode(accelerometerData?.base64EncodedString() , forKey: .accelerometerData)
        try container.encode(gyroscopeData?.base64EncodedString() , forKey: .gyroscopeData)
        try container.encode(motionData?.base64EncodedString() , forKey: .motionData)
        try container.encode(magnetometerData?.base64EncodedString() , forKey: .magnetometerData)
    }

}
```

Now you can easily encode an instance

```
do {
    let sessionData = try JSONEncoder().encode(session)
    // do something with sessionData
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Beatiful answer, Thank you !

Comment: Though I found that saving as a string took less space, That is, saving `sessionData.base64Encoding()` took more space than saving the output of each gyroscope component (time, x, y, and z combined) as a string of comma separated values:

Comment: That is, this string was actually, unexpectedly, smaller when saved to a file: 
"gyrT = {69843.633228625,69843.643237625,69843.653241625,...
gyrX = {-0.575581549547774,-0.439256730191598,...
gyrY = {1.71642702994814,1.45728947165852...
gyrZ = {-0.0592598616281162,0.0245514157733315,..."

Answer (score 0):

Convert your managedObject to a dictionary and then convert that dictionary into json.

```
extension TestSession {
    @NSManaged var bootTime: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var accelerometerData: Data?// Decode Data into Dictionary
    @NSManaged var gyroscopeData: Data?// Decode Data into Dictionary
    @NSManaged var motionData: Data?// Decode Data into Dictionary
    @NSManaged var magnetometerData: Data?// Decode Data into Dictionary

    var toJson: [String: AnyObject] {
        var dictionary: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
        let properties = self.entity.propertiesByName
        for (key, description) in properties {
            if let value = self.value(forKey: key) {
                dictionary[key] = value as AnyObject
            }
        }
        return dictionary
    }

}
```

In your api call method just pass your `managedObject` and then use it like this..

```
func makeAPICall(session: TestSession) {
    var requesst = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://yourURL.com/api")!)
    requesst.httpMethod = "POST"
    do{
        let jsonData = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: session.toJson, options: .prettyPrinted)
        requesst.httpBody = jsonData
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requesst, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

        }).resume()
    }
    catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: `Data` is not JSON compliant. And forget `.prettyPrinted`. The server doesn't care.

Comment: decode data first and make it a dictionary and then add.